# Managing AJAX JSON WebAPI Calls from jQueryMobile page

Tags: ajax, json, jquery, asp.net-web-api

Consider this: my jQueryMobile page has approximately 5 dropdowns. We decided on using WebAPI (novice in this) for DB connection and wrote 5 respective controllers.
Now my basic query, Is there a way to minimize these Ajax calls for populating each of these dropdowns.

For now I am repeating the below code 5 times:

```
$.getJSON('http://<localhost>:63330/api/data/').done(function (data) {

    var listItems = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        alert(data[i]);
        listItems += "<option value='" + i + "'>" + data[i] + "</option>";
    }
    $("#ddlDCName").html(listItems);
    })
    .error(function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("error: " + XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simple make it as a function

```
var getJSONForDropdown = function(url,elementId){
    $.getJSON(url).done(function (data) {
                var listItems = "";
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    alert(data[i]);
                    listItems += "<option value='" + i + "'>" + data[i] + "</option>";
                }
                $(elementId).html(listItems);
            })
           .error(function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                  alert("error: " + XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
            });
}
```

and then call it with different url and elementId of your choice.

```
getJSONForDropdown('http://<localhost>:63330/api/data/',"#ddlDCName");
```

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want all the drop down menus to be populated. It would be better to do this in one ajax call. Multiple ajax calls will slow down things terribly.

Instead of making calls to different controllers get one controller to send you all the data at once ?
Once you have the data filter through it and append it to the respective drop downs.